# How to generate a Random token of 32 bit in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to generate an accurate 32 bits random alphanumeric string in JavaScript.
Is there any direct function to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'accurate?"

Comment: Do you mean 32 characters?

Comment: The size should be of 32 bit, I need to make up a Hash.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 32-bit alphanumeric string? What encoding? One does not traditionally measure string length in bits.

Comment: @NickBailey, that is the tough thing. I have been asked to take a random 32 bit string. Not 32 characters.

Comment: Well then it sounds like you need to ask someone for some clarification.

Comment: @Rahul See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859826/how-to-efficiently-read-bits-out-of-bytes

Comment: @Rahul Can you update Question to clarify actual requirement, and expected result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`crypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) and a [**typed array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array);

```
function random32bit() {
    let u = new Uint32Array(1);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(u);
    let str = u[0].toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return '00000000'.slice(str.length) + str;
}
```

This gives us a 32-bit crypto-random number represented as a zero-padded string of 8 chars (base 16)

---

If you want to extend this to arbitrary numbers of chars;

```
function randomHash(nChar) {
    let nBytes = Math.ceil(nChar = (+nChar || 8) / 2);
    let u = new Uint8Array(nBytes);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(u);
    let zpad = str => '00'.slice(str.length) + str;
    let a = Array.prototype.map.call(u, x => zpad(x.toString(16)));
    let str = a.join('').toUpperCase();
    if (nChar % 2) str = str.slice(1);
    return str;
}
```

---

In ES5, with comments

```
function randomHash(nChar) {
    // convert number of characters to number of bytes
    var nBytes = Math.ceil(nChar = (+nChar || 8) / 2);

    // create a typed array of that many bytes
    var u = new Uint8Array(nBytes);

    // populate it wit crypto-random values
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(u);

    // convert it to an Array of Strings (e.g. "01", "AF", ..)
    var zpad = function (str) {
        return '00'.slice(str.length) + str
    };
    var a = Array.prototype.map.call(u, function (x) {
        return zpad(x.toString(16))
    });

    // Array of String to String
    var str = a.join('').toUpperCase();
    // and snip off the excess digit if we want an odd number
    if (nChar % 2) str = str.slice(1);

    // return what we made
    return str;
}
```

Comment: _"This gives us a 32-bit crypto-random number"_ Would 64 bits be returned at first example?

Comment: @guest271314 I've written a method which lets you generate any multiple of 4 bits :) also, I don't see where you think a 64 bit value would be coming from in my first code block - it's using a `Uint32Array`

Comment: Is it a JS ? Its giving syntax error of missing semicolon

Comment: @Rahul this is ES6, if you want ES5 then you just have to write the two arrow functions the old fashioned way as function expressions

Comment: @PaulS. thank you for your support but can you provide me with the function for ES5 as it is tough for me to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulS.  _"also, I don't see where you think a 64 bit value would be coming from in my first code block"_ https://jsfiddle.net/91hb2n7k/4/ , see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12205668/

Comment: @Rahul Added ES5, comments, bells and whistles.

Comment: @PaulS. Note, first example appears to return all uppercase letter characters?

Comment: @guest271314 now make a 4096 bit one :)

Comment: @PaulS. Note, 32 bits is equivalent to 4 bytes. Both examples appear return 8 bytes, or 64 bits? If you adjust `/ 2` to `/ 4` 32 bits should be returned

Comment: @guest271314 `randomHash(); // "9151E796"` is `91` `51` `E7` `96`, 4 bytes = 32 bits....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112625/discussion-between-paul-s-and-guest271314).

Comment: Actually the requirement is to send a 32 bit string as a token in a post request. Rest thank you for all the efforts you guys put.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to generate an accurate 32 bits random alphanumeric string in
>   JavaScript.

If you mean 32 characters, you can use `URL.createObjectURL`, `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.replace()`

```
var rand = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([])).slice(-36).replace(/-/g, "")
```

Comment: What is the size of a character in JS ?

Comment: @Rahul What do you mean by "size"?

Comment: @Rahul See [How many bytes in a JavaScript string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string) , https://jsfiddle.net/91hb2n7k/

Comment: Thank you. I am trying the answers provided. Will reply back soon and @guest271314 thank you for the link.

Comment: @Rahul Since 4 bytes is equivalent to 32 bits you remove `.replace()`,  use `-4` at `.slice()` `var rand = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([])).slice(-4)` https://jsfiddle.net/91hb2n7k/1/

Comment: @guest271314 do you realize 32 bits is different to 32 characters. If 1 character was 1 bit we'd be really limited when trying to have a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Paul S.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37378421/10713574) but a little simpler:

```
const Token = () => {
  const array = new Uint32Array(1)
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)
  return array[0].toString(36)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function returnHash(){
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".split("");
    var token=""; 
    for(i=0;i<32;i++){
         token += abc[Math.floor(Math.random()*abc.length)];
    }
    return token; //Will return a 32 bit "hash"
}
```

Use by calling `returnHash()`

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the 32 bit random alphanumeric string as requested:

```
crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(4)).reduce((p,c)=>p+String.fromCharCode(c))
```